# "400 Bad Request" when using remote repository of Golang

Tags: go, artifactory, goproxy

I have set up a Golang remote repository named "golang-remote" which points to `https://proxy.golang.org`.

When I tried to use it with `go get`by setting the GOPROXY to `https://<artifactory-service-url>/artifactory/api/go/golang-remote`, I got the error **400 Bad Request**.

I'm not quite familiar with setting up a caching proxy for Golang packages, are there any wrong configurations to my remote repository or wrong usage?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Artifactory only supports the [resolution of Go packages from virtual Go repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Go+Registry#GoRegistry-ResolvingGoProjects). To resolve Go from other local or remote Go repositories, you need to aggregate them in a virtual Go repository.

Create a [virtual repo](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories) example: "go" and include the remote repository "golang-remote" to associate it with the virtual repo. Once done set the GOPROXY

```
export GOPROXY="https://username:api key@my.artifactory.server/artifactory/api/go/go"
```

After that try the `go get`.